# Exterior exhaust piping

Tags: fireplace

Exterior Piping for an open garage wood burning fireplace AFTER the triple wall piping passes thru the exterior wall.  The exterior siding is conc. hardi board.  Can the exhaust pipe going up be single wall?  What clearance away from the siding should it be if single wall piping is used?

Comment: Think your local government would tell you what you can do+

Comment: for singe wall you're looking at about 3 feet clearance, but check your local regulations.